# Php typehinting in called method of object, created in base class

Tags: php, phpdoc, type-hinting

I have the following situation:

```
class Main {
   function get() {
       return new Query();
   }
}

class Order extends Main {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

class Query {
    /**
     * @return Main
     */
    function execute() {
        /// some code here
        return $parsedObject;
    }
}
```

When I use this code to execute() and get Order objects (as parsed object), I'm writing this:

```
$order = new Order();
$result = $order->get()->execute();
$result->id; /// typehint not works, cuz $result is type of Main, not more concrete type Order
```

So my question is - is there any way to pass a type of base (abstract class, interface) class implementation to method, that is called from that base class, for getting beautiful typehint of created object. Cuz i can create User, that extends Main class, with his own fields. But calling new User()->get()->excute() will give me the same result - an object of type Main

Comment: `$result->$id` won't work anyway, first it's `$result->id` but since that property is private you can't access it directly.

Comment: Imagine that props have public access, $result calls id prop. That's not main idea of problem

Comment: I've edited my post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate just about anything, here is your code with everything annotated.

[image: Type Hint]

```
/**
 * Class Main
 */
class Main {

    /**
     * @return Query
     */
   function get() {
       return new Query();
   }
}

/**
 * Class Order
 */
class Order 
    extends Main {

    /** @var int */
    public $id;

    /** @var string */
    public $name;
}

/**
 * Class Query
 */
class Query {

    /**
     * @return Main
     */
    function execute() {
        /// some code here
        return $parsedObject;
    }
}
```